# GridMvc not filtering all Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, filtering

I'm using GridMvc with asp.net mvc 4.5. All of the filters are working except a few strings. I can't see any difference between these strings and the strings that are working. What am I missing?

View
    @model Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.Web.Models.AccountHistoryVM
    @using GridMvc.Html

```
<h2>Account History</h2>    
@Html.Grid(Model.Records).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(m => m.CustomerNo_).Titled("Account #").Filterable(false); 
    columns.Add(m => m.PostingDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").SetWidth(100).Titled("Order Date").Filterable(true); //filter
    columns.Add(m => m.DocumentType).Titled("Type").Filterable(true); //filters
    **columns.Add(m => m.DocumentNo_).Titled("Document #").Filterable(true); //doesn't filter**
    columns.Add(m => m.Description).Titled("Description").SetWidth(300).Filterable(true); //filters
    **columns.Add(m => m.ExternalDocumentNo_).Titled("Memo").SetWidth(300).Filterable(true); //doesn't filter**
    columns.Add(m => m.Amount).Format("{0:$#,###.00}").Titled("Original Amount").SetWidth(200).Filterable(true); //filters
    columns.Add(m => m.RemainingAmount).Format("{0:$#,###.00}").SetWidth(100).Titled("Remaining Amount").Filterable(true); //filters
    columns.Add(m => m.DueDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Titled("Due Date").Filterable(true); 
}).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true) //filters
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models
{
    [Table("CustLedgerEntry")]
    public class CustLedgerEntry
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int EntryNo_ { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string CustomerNo_ { get; set; }

        public DateTime PostingDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }


        [StringLength(20)]
        public string DocumentNo_ { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [StringLength(35)]
        public string ExternalDocumentNo_ { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal RemainingAmount { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime DatetoWebSales { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Open { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AccountHistory()
{

    var dealerId = db.UserProfiles.Where(d => d.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).Select(d => d.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();

    var vm = new AccountHistoryVM();
    vm.Records = db.CustLedgerEntries.ToList().Where(x => x.CustomerNo_.Equals(dealerId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    var datetoweb = db.CustLedgerEntries.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DatetoWebSales != null);
    vm.LastUpdatedDate = datetoweb.DatetoWebSales;
    return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have just removed underscore(_) from model and your grid it is working fine now.

> Model

[image: Grid]

> Grid

```
    <div class="container">
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(m => m.CustomerNo_).Titled("Account #").Filterable(false);
    columns.Add(m => m.PostingDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").SetWidth(100).Titled("Order Date").Filterable(true); //filter
    columns.Add(m => m.DocumentType).Titled("Type").Filterable(true); //filters
    columns.Add(m => m.DocumentNo).Titled("Document").Filterable(true); //doesn't filter**
    columns.Add(m => m.Description).Titled("Description").SetWidth(300).Filterable(true); //filters
    columns.Add(m => m.ExternalDocumentNo).Titled("Memo").SetWidth(300).Filterable(true); //doesn't filter**
    columns.Add(m => m.Amount).Format("{0:$#,###.00}").Titled("Original Amount").SetWidth(200).Filterable(true); //filters
    columns.Add(m => m.RemainingAmount).Format("{0:$#,###.00}").SetWidth(100).Titled("Remaining Amount").Filterable(true); //filters
    columns.Add(m => m.DueDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Titled("Due Date").Filterable(true);
}).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true) 
    </div>
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Saineshwar. Is there a way to fix this in the model without actually changing the table? This data is coming from our ERP and I'd rather not have to change the program that's pushing this data into SQL if possible.

Comment: @JoshMcGee you can create a new model (removing underscore) and assign value to it which is coming from ERP that model.